# Redirecting all links to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, server

I redirect all link to "public" directory width:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but it gives me always "500 Internal Server Error"

if i write concrent path it will work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/page/
```

but if I put dynamic variable $i it give me 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

This will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error) unless it rewrites to a physical file. You need to ensure you only rewrite direct requests. You can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The `QSA` and `NC` flags are not required here.

OR, use the `END` flag instead on Apache 2.4:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [END]
```